# How can I calculate the IoU between the original image and the predicted one as shown in attached image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, validation, image-processing, image-segmentation

How can I calculate the IoU between the original image and the predicted one, as shown in the attached image?enter image [image: original image]descripti[image: output from the model]on here